# When is the composition of two Gaussian Processes a Gaussian Process?

Tags: stochastic-processes

Say I have a probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, P)$ and two Gaussian Processes over this space $X_1, X_2$ such that:
\begin{align*}
X_1: \mathbb{R} \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\
X_2: \mathbb{R} \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}
\end{align*}

Under what conditions (if any) is the process $X'(\omega, x) = X_1(\omega, X_2(\omega, x))$ also a Gaussian Process? Does this require that $X_1,X_2$ are independent, or just jointly normal?

Comment: Are they assumed to be independent, or at least jointly normal?

Comment: Good question. I will edit the question to express that I am also interested in knowing how these factors affect the answer.

Comment: Actually, even under the independence assumption, I realized that we have the following counter-example: $$X_1(x,\omega)=x^2,\qquad X_2(x,\omega)=Z(\omega),$$ where $Z$ is a normal random variable. Then $X'=Z^2$ is not a Gaussian process.

Comment: I suppose this is based on $X_1$ having zero variance everywhere, right?

Comment: Not really. You can add to $X_1$ another independent gaussian process and still we get a non-gaussian process. The point is that, any non-linear transformation would destroy normality.

Comment: Thanks for the context. If you write this as an answer I can accept it.